# How to use cURL to hit a Proxy Server in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, curl, networking, proxy

I want to be able to eavesdrop on the HTTP messages that reach one of my micro-services (MS). I figured that the only possible way to do is to have a proxy that forwards all packets to the MS upon doing whatever it wants to do.

So I have a MS written in java and is listening on port (say) 9999. It has a *REST* **GET** interface. So when I start it and do:

```
curl http://localhost:9999/service/hello/mean
```

It returns, **'Hello mean!'** as expected.Now I am trying to eavesdrop on all similar messages and I have a simple proxy-service.

What the proxy-service does is creates a **ServerSocket** on a port (say) **8080** and is listening for connections. And the only thing as of now it does is just **accept()** s connections and read bytes from the socket stream and writes to a **Socket** connection to the port where the micro-service is listening on *(which is 9999 in this case)*.

So now, I have:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
```

I am using the inputstream from **ss** to read from client and to write to server via socket **server**.

With this setup, I am doing **cURL** to port **8080** where the proxy is listening on:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/service/hello/mean
```

I am expecting the proxy to forward the request directly to the MS and return back. But this does not seem to work.

What principals have I missed in understanding the flow?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**------------------------------------**

### **EDIT**

I was able to find one initial problem that was preventing from this setup to work, which is that I had ***some other process*** listening on **PORT 8080**. So I changed the *proxy-port* to something else *(say 9099)*.

Now, I am able to hit the _proxy service and also get the appropriate response.

Thank you
Shabir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able figure-out the issue(s).
My setup was indeed correct and was appropriate to do what I wanted to do.

As my **EDIT** above suggests, I had some *other process* listening on **PORT 8080** of my machine, hence the *proxy did not work correctly*. When I changed the *proxy port* to something else *(say 9099)* this works fine.

Then, the entire flow works as expected.

Thank you
Shabir